# cat in multiple ssh commands does not work

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, heredoc

This is probably very basic but unfortunately I have no idea how to google it.

Why doesn't the snippet below work as expected? I mean, how can I make `cat` point to the remote file?

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh user@remoteaddress << EOF
  mkdir sandpit
  cd sandpit
  echo "foo" > foo.txt
  echo `cat foo.txt` > foo2.txt
EOF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use it as:

```
ssh -t -t user@remoteaddress<<'EOF'
mkdir sandpit
cd sandpit
echo "foo" > foo.txt
cat foo.txt > foo2.txt
xargs kill < pid.txt
exit
EOF
```

Without quotes around starting `EOF` all words are subject to shell expansion and reverse quotes are expanded in your current shell not on ssh.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Well, what I actually want to do is `kill \`cat pid.txt\``. How should I do in this case?

Comment: Now I've checked the edit and everything's solved. thank you very much.